# .net construct / pattern to block by segment of code, not by thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, design-patterns, .net-4.0

Is there a construct or pattern in .net that defines a segment of code that can be accessed by multiple threads but blocks if any thread is in some other segment of code (and vice-versa)?  For example:

```
void SomeOperationA()
{
    Block( B ) 
    {   
        Segment1: 
        ... only executes if no threads are executing in Segment2 ... 
    }    
}

}

void SomeOperationB()
{
    Block( A ) 
    { 
        Segment2: 
        ... only executes if no threads are executing in Segment1 ... 
    }     
}
```

**Edit**
Several threads should be able to access Segment1/Segment2 simultaneously (only one Segment being "active" at a time.  If Segment 1 is executing, another thread should be able to execute Segment1 but not Segment2.


**Edit 2**

Given all the comments/replies and my real-world scenario, I realize that its a bit crazy to require Segment2 to be accessed by multiple-threads.

Comment: can several threads execute Segment2 simultaneously?

Comment: Sounds like a recipe for starvation.

Comment: @SFun28: What is the real world application of this?

Comment: Here's the scenario in real-world terms: Segment2 serializes a ConcurrentDictionary to disk.  Happens time-to-time.  When serializing, we must ensure that the dictionary is stable.  Segment1 reads and/or alters the data.  It is thread-safe since ConcurrentDictionary is thread-safe.  We want high-throughput in Segment1, but we want to stop the show if executing Segment2.  If we attempt to execute Segment2, we want to hold the line until we are done with Segment1 executions.  hope that helps.

Comment: To add to my "real-world" scenario above: The calling code won't monopolize segment 1 - probably segment 1 will be hit hard for some period of time, then segment 2 will be called, and so on.  The mechanism is just in place for safety measures.

Comment: By the way...is this just a ReaderWriterLockSlim?

Comment: @SFun28: See my answer - if that's the case, you really should only allow a single "Segment2" (serialization) thread, in which case ReaderWriterLockSlim is perfect.

Comment: ReaderWriterLock/ManualResetEvent ... both can solve this problem :)

Comment: What you have to do is 1) Maintain who's turn is now: Segment1 or Segment2 2) Count amount of threads that got into current Segment 3) When it comes to 0 make possible for other threads to capture resource.

Comment: All - I'm sorry, I should have put more thought into the scenario.  I will accept @LBushkin's answer for solving my actual scenario, but I appreciate @Andrey's answer and other attempts to solve the scenario I first posted about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is a rather unusual model for protecting resources from improper concurrent access.** I would first consider whether your use case can't be translated into an equivalent scenario where you can use simple locks. If you could provide more details on why you need this kind of locking scheme it may be possible for the community to offer other ideas.

**To address your specific question, nothing in .NET or even Win32 directly supports this locking model,** however you may be able to build it out of other primitives. <strike>I would look at using a pair of [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) instances to protect each resource. As threads enter SegmentA you aquire a write read lock on A and a write lock B ... and vice verse for threads entering SegmentB. This would allow multiple threads to execute within each segment, but not at the same time</strike>.

**EDIT**: **Given your reply in the comments to your question, I am more convinced you need to look at using a Reader/Writer locking model.** What you're looking for is a way to protect a resource such that when "writers" are doing work (serializing the dictionary) no readers or other writers can enter and when "readers" are doing work they don't block each other but block all other writers. This is a classic case for reader/writer locks.

**EDIT 2**: *Now that I've have more time, I think it's worth elaborating on one points. The way to think about locks is that they protect data resources (memory, files, etc) rather than areas of code. The fact that we need to define critical sections of code that only one thread at a time can enter is an implementation detail that one shouldn't confuse with how shared resources are used (and must be protected). In your question, the focus on how to control which threads can enter which section of code misdirects from the real problem: which data resources you are trying to protect against what kind of changes. Once you look at the problem from that perspective, it makes it clearer which implementation paradigms make sense.*

**Here are some good resources on reader/writer locking models:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163599.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz6sth95.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2006/03/29/564854.aspx

Comment: I think what makes this unusual is multi-thread access to Segment2. If we say that only one thread can access Segment2 at a time, but hold all the other requirements, I think this just reduces to a ReaderWriterLockSlim, correct?

Comment: It will not work with `ReaderWriterLockSlim` and here is why. You can't enter Write lock simultaneously. This will become mutual exclusion and eventually only one thread will be able to execute SegmentA

Comment: The pair of ReaderWriterLocks, as described, doesn't work.  As soon as you grab the write lock, you're preventing two threads from executing that block simulateously...

Comment: @SFun28: Yes, I believe that's correct. However, I would encourage this kind of reduction as it puts you into known territory for using locking ... rather than out in the wilderness.

Comment: @Reed Copsey: Yes, I believe you're correct. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given your edit, it sounds like the proper approach would be to use a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx), since you really shouldn't be modifying the collection when Segment2 is running, and you shouldn't allow more than 1 Segment2 to run:

```
private static ReaderWriterLockSlim readerLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
void SomeOperationA()
{
    try
    {  
        readerLock.EnterReadLock(); 
        // Segment1: 
        // ... only executes if no threads are executing in Segment2 ... 
    }    
    finally
    {
        readerLock.ExitReadLock();
    }
}

void SomeOperationB()
{
    try
    {  
        readerLock.EnterWriteLock(); 
        // Prevents multiple Segment2 from serializing, and prevents all Segment1 threads...
    }    
    finally
    {
        readerLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

Comment: He didn't say that Segment2 can't be executed simultaneously. Simple `lock` will not help if it is true.

Comment: @Andrey: Yes- I had edited to include that - if that's a requirement, things get a bit trickier...

Comment: sorry, I meant to include that.  Yes, two threads should be able to execute Segment1/2 simultaneously (but not both segments at the same time!)

Comment: `SomeOperationB()` can't be executed simultaneously. They should work the same.

Comment: @Andrey: Given the OPs comments about the goal here, I don't believe that's true...

Answer (score 0):

Sort of like that.

```
    class Segments
    {
        public const int None = 0;
        public const int Segm1 = 1;
        public const int Segm2 = 2;
    }

    int currentSegm = 0;
    int segm1counter = 0;
    int segm2counter = 0;

    object segm1lock = new object();
    object segm2lock = new object();

    void SomeOperationA()
    {
        while (
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref currentSegm, Segments.Segm1, Segments.Segm1) != Segments.Segm1
            &&
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref currentSegm, Segments.Segm1, Segments.None) != Segments.None
            )
        {
            Thread.Yield();
        }

        Interlocked.Increment(ref segm1counter);
        try
        {

            //Segment1: 
            //... only executes if no threads are executing in Segment2 ...                 
        }
        finally
        {
            lock (segm1lock)
            {
                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref segm1counter) == 0)
                    currentSegm = Segments.None;
            }
        }
    }


    void SomeOperationB()
    {
        while (
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref currentSegm, Segments.Segm2, Segments.Segm2) != Segments.Segm2
            &&
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref currentSegm, Segments.Segm2, Segments.None) != Segments.None
            )
        {
            Thread.Yield();
        }

        Interlocked.Increment(ref segm2counter);
        try
        {

            //Segment2: 
            //... only executes if no threads are executing in Segment2 ...                 
        }
        finally
        {
            lock (segm2lock)
            {
                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref segm2counter) == 0)
                    currentSegm = Segments.None;
            }
        }
    }
```

Ok, it will not work with ReaderWriter locking/

Comment: I had though along these lines - but the write locks prevent 2 simultaneous threads, which effectively turns this into a single "lock" call.

Comment: Thanks so much for coding-up a solution to my original post.  I now realize my original scenario is quite crazy.

Comment: @SFun28 it is interesting puzzle. I didn't get much into root cause.